# count number of cases by cut off date

Tags: r

Hi I'm struggling with how to count number of cases given a cut off date. On Table A I have IDs with cut off dates attached to each ID. On Table B I have IDs with dates where a claim case happened. I hope to count the number of cases that an ID has been through by cut off date on Table A.

Table A

```
ID     Date       
A    2019-01-03      
A    2019-05-03      
A    2019-09-23      
B    2019-02-04      
B    2019-03-16
```

Table B

```
ID   Claim_Date   
 A    2018-12-03      
 A    2019-04-23      
 B    2019-03-16
```

I want to achieve below data structure:

```
ID     Date           Claims

A       2019-01-03         1  
A       2019-05-03         2   
A       2019-09-23         2   
B       2019-02-04         0   
B       2019-03-16         1
```

I've been trying multiple ways but nothing worked. Could someone help me on this? Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following with dply, tidyr and lubridate

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

# Transform to date columns
TableA <- TableA %>%
    mutate(Date = lubridate::date(Date))

TableB <- TableB %>%
    mutate(Claim_Date = lubridate::date(Claim_Date))

# Join Tables and count Dates greater or equal than Claim Dates.
TableA %>%
 left_join(TableB) %>%
 mutate(Claims = ifelse(Date >= Claim_Date,1,0)) %>%
 group_by(ID, Date) %>%
 summarise(Claims = sum(Claims))
```